# JavaScript not reading variable value in else code

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to print the log for following JavaScript. However, script is not printing the log value. I highlighted the variable value the script should identify in the `if`/`else` code, however after `else` it is not reading the `$systemDate` from outside the `if`/`else` statement; as a result it is not logging the value for `$dueDate`. I am trying following code:

```
_wait(_div("/date-display .* bwc-selected/"));
var $date = _getText(_div("/date-display .* bwc-selected/"));

_wait(2000);

_log($date);

_wait(2000);


var str = ($date)

    var d = new Date(str)

        var $systemDate = (d.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ d.getUTCDate() + "/" + d.getUTCFullYear();

_log('System Date is:' + $systemDate);




var $dueDate = person.$dueDate;

if ($dueDate != null)

{
    var $dueDate = person.$dueDate;

    person.$dueDate = $dueDate;

    _log('Due Date is:' + $dueDate);


}

else

{

    var $days = 90;

    var $theDate = new Date($systemDate);

    var $pregnancyDueDate = new Date($theDate);

    $pregnancyDueDate.setDate($pregnancyDueDate.getDate() + $days);



    var due = ($pregnancyDueDate);

    var n = new Date(due);

        var $dueDate =  (n.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ n.getUTCDate() + "/" + n.getUTCFullYear();

    _log('Due Date is:' + $dueDate);


    person.$dueDate = $dueDate;


}
```

Comment: What is `_log()` ?

Comment: Oh God!! Please, please read about javascript variable scoping.

Comment: Its because you are re-declaring the variable in both scopes which aren't really scopes to be precise

Comment: hi Weedoze - here are the log:   _log("Thursday 16 Mar 2017")
_wait(2000)
_log("Curam System Date is:" + "3/16/2017")
_log("Pregnancy Due Date is:" + "")

Comment: Another thing is that in the first If statement script will try to read value from the excel sheet if script won't find value in the script then script will go for Else statement where script will call $systemDate and 90 days and use that date further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not redeclare your variable !
remove var from

```
var $dueDate =  (n.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ n.getUTCDate() + "/" + n.getUTCFullYear();
```

it should be:

```
$dueDate =  (n.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ n.getUTCDate() + "/" + n.getUTCFullYear();
```

You variable was already declared here before your if

```
var $dueDate = person.$dueDate;
```

and finally update your if condition to :

```
if ($dueDate != "")
```

because your cells can be just empty and not containing null values

Comment: hi Loay - Script is reading _log('Curam System Date is:' + $systemDate);  and retrieving $systemDate but not calling $systemDate after Else which should happen.

Comment: Another thing is that in the first If statement script will try to read value from the excel sheet if script won't find value in the script then script will go for Else statement where script will call $systemDate and 90 days and use that date further.

Comment: Did you try outputing your systemData to see if it is correct ? Before doing `var $theDate = new Date($systemDate);` verify that your variable is correctly set by outputting it. 
I also have a question why are you doing `var $theDate = new Date($systemDate);` and then `var $pregnancyDueDate = new Date($theDate);` Why aren't you doing `var $pregnancyDueDate = new Date($systemDate);` directly?

Comment: Another question are you using javascript or jquery ?

Comment: Loay - I am using JavaScript. I tried outputting $systemDate after Else but it is not printing the $systemDate there. It should Print $systemDate after Else.

Comment: okay you can start by removing all the $ that are before your variables names because $ are for jquery instances. Modify this code first and tell me if it changes anything

Comment: also try to print system date just after affecting a value to it (ie: after `var $systemDate = (d.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ d.getUTCDate() + "/" + d.getUTCFullYear();`

Comment: hi Loay - Script is printing $systemDate after var $systemDate = (d.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ d.getUTCDate() + "/" + d.getUTCFullYear();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138235/discussion-between-loay-ashmawy-and-curious).

Comment: hi Loay - I just removed $dueDate != null ||    from the     if ($dueDate != null || $dueDate != "")  becuase it was not working for me with $dueDate != null ||